# Using PagedList.Mvc to create pages in my view gives me build error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, pagination

I have a Project that I need to add Pagination to but I keep getting an error.  I find this link, [http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/), on the MSDN site.  I am working through it and install the PagedList.MVC nuget package, put this code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TechOpenTickets(int? page)
{

      ViewBag.Title = "Open Tickets Assigned To Me";

      var model = FindTechTickets(new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveID));

      int pageSize = 3;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
      return View("TechOpen", model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

}
```

and then in my view, I have this at the top:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<HelpDesk.Model.Ticket>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
```

I am receiving the following build error on the PagedList keywords in the view.

> The type or namespace name 'PagedList' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I already installed the nuget package, what am I missing?

Comment: Please include the build error message in your post.

Comment: @Sybren, added above. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you make sure that you have PagedList and PagedList.Mvc in your Project References.

If that seems okay try to clean the solution and rebuild it.

Your compiler can't seem to find the location of PagedList and these seems to be the most likely scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Mohit, I never knew about 'Clean Solution' before.  That fixed it.

Comment: Thanks.I also never thought cleaning solution could fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean Solution.All issues will be fixed.